# Exchange Powershell Error on Something that totally functioned a few months ago?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server

I wrote this a few months ago to loop through a few domains and a userlist and give me a readout of how many emails from the listed domain each user got. Now I'm getting some error that is SUPER weird and I just don't know what it's saying.

Here's the code and the error

```
[long]$IntSent=0
[long]$IntRec=0
[long]$IntTotal=0
$startdate="06/09/2018 00:00:01"
$enddate="06/12/2018 23:59:59"

$domains=@(REDACTED) #etc
$users=@(REDACTED)    

ForEach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($domain in $domains) {
get-messagetrackinglog -start $startdate  -End $enddate -Recipients $users -resultsize unlimited -EventID Receive | where {[string]$_.sender -like "*@$domain"} |ForEach{$IntRec++}
#|Where {[String]$_.recipients -notlike "*@contoso4.com*"}
}
}
```

And the error:

```
The server software doesn't support the type of search requested.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-MessageTrackingLog], LocalizedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 6220E2A4,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.GetMessageTrackingLog
    + PSComputerName        : MUHSERVER

The server software doesn't support the type of search requested.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-MessageTrackingLog], LocalizedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 6220E2A4,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.GetMessageTrackingLog
    + PSComputerName        : MUHSERVER

The server software doesn't support the type of search requested.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-MessageTrackingLog], LocalizedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 6220E2A4,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.GetMessageTrackingLog
    + PSComputerName        : MUHSERVER
```

Thoughts? I have no idea where to look here.

Comment: *Thoughts?* I think all those users at your company are going to love you dumping their email addresses into your post here.

Comment: You may want to remove this question and re-post, and sanitize your script and output (editing the post will retain the sensitive info as a previous revision). Also this might be a better question for SuperUser or ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is most likely related with too many proxy addresses. As you can see [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ba4b2c09-9c11-4feb-aca4-adfd22e918c0/message-tracking-fails-with-the-server-software-doesnt-support-the-type-of-search-requested-for?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy) (not in the answer but below):

> if the mailbox has more than 49 proxy addresses entered within the Email addresses tab the search command will fail

This would explain why it was working before and isn't working now. While in general the solution would be to check if any user has more than 49 proxy addresses, this might not be the case here.

In your `ForEach` you use

```
-Recipients $users
```

so basically for each user you do the search for messages sent to **all** users from your list. What you probably wanted to use is (notice lack of `s`)

```
-Recipients $user
```

Also, if I might suggest something (as a good habit) - I usually use one character variables while iterating using `ForEach` like this:

```
ForEach ($u in $users)
ForEach ($d in $domains)
```

With that habit you minimize the likelihood of using incorrect variable in `ForEach` as in that script.